# Argument type does not conform to Encodable

Tags: ios, swift, networking, codable, encodable

I am trying to create a Struct for a POST request. The struct conforms, to the best of my knowledge to the `Codable` typealias but I keep getting the error

> Argument type 'RegisterUserRequest.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable' " when passing it in as a parameter to my `JSONEncoder`.

I have tried to conform only to `Encodable`, to write the suggested required init() but nothing seems to work.

This is the way my Struct looks like

```
struct RegisterUserRequest: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var dateOfBirth: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case email
        case phoneNumber = "phone"
        case dateOfBirth = "date_of_birth"
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you need to pass an object of a type that conforms to `Codable` / `Encodable` not the type itself

```
do {
    let instance = RegisterUserRequest(firstname:////////......
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(instance)
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```